# How to test the login method in the Site class

Tags: apex, unit-test, community

I'm getting the error: attempting to reference a null value when trying to test the login method of the Site class. I've tried to see if I can get any error messages. It might be that I'm not creating the community user correct? Here is my test class:

```
System.runAs(t.adminUser){
    vetAccount = t.createDefaultAccount(randomAccountLastName);
    insert vetAccount;
    communityContact = t.createDefaultContact(randomContactLastName, vetAccount.Id);
    insert communityContact;
    communityUser = t.createDefaultPortalUser(randomEmail, randomContactLastName, randomEmail,randomAlias,communityContact.Id);
    Site.createPortalUser(communityUser,String.valueOf(vetAccount.Id),'1234', false);
}
System.runAs(communityUser){
    CustomLoginController controller = new CustomLoginController();
    t.start();
        controller.username = randomEmail;
        controller.password = '1234';
        PageReference pageRef = controller.login();
        List<ApexPages.Message> apexMessages = ApexPages.getMessages();
    t.stop();
        System.assertEquals('', String.valueOf(pageRef.getContent()));
        /*System.assertEquals(' ', apexMessages[0].getSummary());
        System.assertEquals('', pageRef.getUrl());*/
}
```

The `controller.login` is just a wrapper method which returns the page reference from the login method of the Site class.

Looking forward for some answers.

Comment: Please check this...Related to your question- https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_sites.htm